# How to Initilize a variable to use it later in php?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I want to Initialize a variable, and want to use it later in my foreach loop, below is my working:

```
$lastdepdate = "";

$resultDEP  = "SELECT * FROM mytable";

foreach($resultDEP as $rows){
    $lastdepdate         = trim($row['LastDepDate']);
}
```

I am getting date from my table and checking it with today's date **AND**

```
if ($AssetClassID > 01) {
    $returnDep  = $depSL;
} else if($AssetClassID > 02){
    $returnDep  = $Cost;
}

$DepAmount      = $returnDep;
```

How can I achieve this in if and else if loop?

Comment: what do you mean you want to initialize your variable ?? when does it get initialized ?? and when do you use it in foreach loop ?? There is not enough clarity

Comment: I want to store foreach result into a variable as well as for if statement as well, but it's throwing an error as it is not initialized first, so how can I get this task done?

Comment: It is because the issue of if statement scope and maybe same for the foreach loop, but what I need is to get an answer by which I can store my values into variables by initializing it first and later use it in the if statement block and foreach block so it may have the value, will it or not? or any other option should I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the variable before the `if` or `for` statements.
You could also define an array

```
<?php
$arr = array();

if ($condition == true) {
    $arr[] = "Val";
} else {
    $arr[] = "OtherVal";
}

DoSomething($arr[0]);


?>
```

This way, you don't need to worry about having trouble accessing a variable defined in a loop. This is because adding something to an array, doesn't count as defining the variable in the loop. Instead, it is like running a function.

For a `foreach` loop, if the array method **does not work**, (It should), try this:

```
<?php
$RandomVar = null;
function setIt($v) {
  $RandomVar = $v;
}
function getIt() {
  return $RandomVar;
}

foreach($arr as $node) {
  //do whatever
  setIt($whatever);
}

DoWhatever(getIt());

?>
```

Comment: I have defined a variable before if and foreach statements, see my code blocks, but It's not working.

Comment: Did the array method work?

Comment: it worked in if statement but not in foreach statement!

Comment: If you are adding multiple things in the array, every single variable should still be there. If you're not, try the above.